# jQuery Flot Tick/Date Alignment

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, flot

### Code

Example of my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/x46RQ/

---

### Goal

I want the graph to be a bar graph like so: http://jsfiddle.net/Lbd85/ but obviously with dates as the x axis. If I add my data into that fiddle, it messes up like the one listed above as seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/73G7Z/

---

### Questions

- Why are all 3 days provided in the data variable not displaying?
- Why are the bars not lined up with their appropriate x-axis ticks?
- Why does changing the data and mode to time totally mess up what would otherwise be a functional and accurate bar graph?

---

### Environment

- jQuery 1.7.1
- jQuery Mobile 1.0.1
- Flot 0.7

---

### Thanks

Let me know if any additional information is required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Part #1,  You specified a min y value of 0 in your flot options, and your data point #2 has a value of zero.  So it's there but just very small, almost invisible.

Part #2, you have to offset your dates by the users timezone:

Something like this:

```
var tzOffset = new Date();
tzOffset = tzOffset.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000;
data.push([(new Date("2012/02/20").getTime()-tzOffset), 1]);
```

Part #3, Your graph is a mess because you specified a `width` when in fact the option you were looking for is `barWidth` and you need to specify the width in terms of time, i.e. milliseconds.  See [here](http://code.google.com/p/flot/issues/detail?id=275#c9) for how.  Something like `barWidth: 12*60*60*1000` looks OK.

So in summary, this is what it will look like:  http://jsfiddle.net/ncTd3/

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Why are the bars not centered and why are the x-axis ticks still off center?  I would really like it to look identical to the bar graph I mentioned in the question.  

Thanks again for your reply.

Comment: In my example jsfiddle, I didn't use the code to calculate the tzOffset, I just set it to mine (PST).  Check it out here, it should work for any timezone now:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/ncTd3/1/